# unable to pas map<string,Object> to apex class from LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-web-components, field-mapping

I need to pass data from LWC to Apexclass, But in apexlass  i am getting it as null, But in LWC console i am getting values. Please help me where i did the wrong.

LWC:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';

import { getRecord, getObjectInfo, getPicklistValues, getFieldValue, updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import getallMetadata from '@salesforce/apex/RegionController.getallMetadata';
import getmdata from '@salesforce/apex/RegionController.getRegion';
import createUpdateMetadata from '@salesforce/apex/RegionController.createUpdateMetadata'; // to save record.

import picklistval from '@salesforce/apex/RegionController.getallMetadatapiclist';


export default class Custmetadata extends LightningElement {
    @track myMap = [];
    @track meatadataLabel;

    handleClick(event) {
        console.log('Inside Button click ' + event.detail.name);
        this.editmode = true;
        this.displaydetails = false;
        const label = event.target.label;

        if (label === 'Update') { }
        else if (label === 'Save') {
        let i;
        let fieldMap;
        let checkboxes = this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-id="checkbox"]')
        for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            this.fieldMap = [...checkboxes].reduce((p, v) => (p[v.name] = p.checked, p), {});
        }
        console.log('myMap data === ' + this.fieldMap);
        console.log('myMap data === ' + JSON.stringify(this.fieldMap));
        createUpdateMetadata({ fullName: this.metadataname, label: this.value, fieldWithValuesMap: this.fieldMap }) //
            .then(result => {
                var options = [];
                if (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}
```

Apex class:

```
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static void createUpdateMetadata(String fullName, String label, Map<String, Object> fieldWithValuesMap){ // 
        Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata =  new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
        system.debug('fieldWithValuesMap --'+fieldWithValuesMap);
        customMetadata.fullName = fullName;
        customMetadata.label = label;
        
        for(String key : fieldWithValuesMap.keySet()){
            Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
            customField.field = key;
            customField.value = fieldWithValuesMap.get(key); 
            customMetadata.values.add(customField);
        }
        
        Metadata.DeployContainer mdContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
        mdContainer.addMetadata(customMetadata);
   
    }
```

Output in LWC console:

```
Prepared map result --- >[{"key":"test","value":true},{"key":"test2","value":true},{"key":"trest3","value":false},{"key":"test4","value":true},{"key":"test233","value":false}]
 this.myMap --- [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

[image]
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You made the Map into an Array, but it should be an Object.

```
let checkboxes = this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-id="checkbox"]');
let fieldMap = [...checkboxes].reduce((p,v) => (p[v.name] = p.checked, p), {});
```

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, Here it is updating, but values are not passing the selected values in the map. Here is the updated code. All values are getting as null. What is the issue ?   let i;
            let fieldMap;
            let checkboxes = this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-id="checkbox"]')

            this.fieldMap = [...checkboxes].reduce((p, v) => (p[v.name] = p.checked, p), {});

            console.log('myMap data === ' + this.fieldMap);
            console.log('myMap data === ' + JSON.stringify(this.fieldMap));

Comment: HI @sfdcfox, This is what am getting as output,  myMap data === [object Object]
 myMap data === {}, Data is not mapping properly. What is the mistake i did it here. Thank you

Comment: @anjireddy Don't know, you haven't edited your question to include the latest version of your code.

Comment: here i need to pass selected and unselected checkbox values as ( string, object) format to apex class variable. Please correct me if i did anything wrong. I updated the code, Please have a look.  Thank you.

Comment: @anjireddy you used my name, fieldMap, but then gave the parameter as this.myMap. Make sure the variable names match. Also, your first parameter appears to be misspelled (`meatadataname` instead of whatever it should be; it doesn't appear to be declared or assigned anywhere).

Comment: I updated the code once again, Please check. Can you help me where is the issue. Thank you.

Comment: @anjireddy You need to make sure the variable name is declared in the class.

Comment: i double checked all variables with class. all variables are same. IN CONSOLE LOG STATEMENTS DATA PRINTING AS NULL, Here only data not preparing. Something i did here is the wrong. i am unable to figure it out.  Thank you.